# Are the German word “Nacht” and the Latin word “nego” cognates?

Tags: etymology, latin

Can anybody please explain to me why the German word *Nacht* and the Latin verb *nego* (not to say) are not cognates by analogy with *recht* and *rego*?

Comment: Your question is hard to answer. You seem to have a strong hypothesis and ask why it is wrong. For us doing so, could you please explain why they should be cognates? There are of course a lot of phonetic analogies which do not make sense at all. _H**aus**_ in German is _h**ouse**_ in English, _Maus_ is _m**ouse**_, but German _her**aus**_ is not _*her**ouse**_ in English and English _ar**ouse**_ is not _*ar**aus**_ in German. So, if your argument is just based on the mere presence of a phonetic analogy, it is a pretty weak argument and it should not surprise you that it's wrong

Comment: Even if it is further away phonetically, you should be looking at *nocturnus*

Comment: Such words are only rarely imported, it is too basic. My first idea was that it roots in some super-ancient old-German, maybe old-proto-indoeuropäisches word. However, tofro's comment seems convincing to me, although I am not a linguist and not a native speaker.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach it's not just a phonetic analogy, but a semantic one, too.

Comment: @vectory Maybe it is a semantic analogy. I fail to see this. The question should make more clear, what the assumptions would lead to the hypothesis. Else it is hard to answer, why the hypothesis is wrong. This was meant to be my main point. This is not an argument on why the hypothesis is wrong, just wanted to demonstrate the need to clarify the question.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach the way I read it, it supposes a latent feature set "to speak [right or wrong]" and the question is how night figures into this. I think the answer is clear as day, but speculative nevertheless, dependent on the origin of *nego* at least (which, would probably require reading italian sources).

Answer (score 7):

### No.

The German word *Nacht* (Middle and Old High German: *naht*), English *night*, Swedish *natt* and Gothic *nahts* (Gothic is an extinct east-germanic language) derive from Proto-Indo-European **noku[t]* (*nák* in Vedic Sanskrit)

The Latin word that derives from that root is *nox* (genitive: *noctis*), and this word simply means: night.

Also the Russian word *ночь* (in Latin letters: *noč*) derives from the same root.

Other German words that derive from the same root are:

- **nächtlich**
  English: *nightly, nocturnal*
- **nüchtern**
  Old High German: *nouhturn* (because nuns and monks didn't eat during the night)
  English: *sober*

And of course also the English word *nocturnal* is derived from Latin *nox, noctis.*

---

From the Latin word *negare* (1st person: *nego*) (to say nothing, to say "no") are derived:

- **negativ**
  English: *negative*
- **negieren**
  English: *to negate*

**So, *Nacht/night* and *negare/nego* have no common roots.**

---

btw:

The German word *recht* does not come from Latin *regere* (1st person: *rego*). But both words derive from the Proto-Indo-European root **reĝ-*. Its original meaning was *to erect, to stretch, to make straight*, later it changed to *to direct, to govern, to judge.*

Also the Latin word *rectus* (straight-line, linear) is derived from it, but also the word *erection.*

Also the German *Rektor* (director of an university) and the German adjective *direkt* and it's English counterpart *direct* are derived from it, also *Regime* (engl: *regime*) and the English *reign* (king, governer, *Regent* in German).

Comment: Little addendum: Latin _nego_ is in all probability derived from _ne_, meaning _not_.

Comment: @sgf Addendum secundum: *nego* seems to be from the universal Indo-European nasal negation (which can take many forms, such as *n* and *ne*) plus the root of Latin *aio* "say yes" ([Lewis & Short](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=nego&filter=CUTF8)), cf. *adagium* and German *ja*. It would seem impossible for these roots to share any origin with the root of *Nacht*.

Comment: And cf. English *aye, yes*.

Comment: @Cerberus So how does _nejo_ become _nego_? Is that a regular thing?

Comment: @sgf: I wish I knew! I paraphrased Lewis & Short. You could ask on http://latin.stackexchange.com. It can perhaps be found in De Vaan.

Comment: My old Stowasser says that the prefix in _nego_ actually comes from _nec_; which in turn is a reduction form of _neque_ before vowels.

Comment: "Its original meaning was to erect" can you prove that? OP likely wrote assuming that *rechnen* relates to *rex* in the sense "commander" or the like (cp. *zählen*, *erzählen*, *Graf*, *Schreiber*, En. *Count, comptesse, recount* etc. for similar analogies). *rect-* might thus derive from a sense *builder*, by backformation, who knows.

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing Latin words with German words in attempting to find cognates. While both languages have Indo-European origins, they belong to different low-level branches as shown in this family tree of the Indo-European languages taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:IndoEuropeanTree.svg):

[image: Indo-European languages family tree]

To go from Latin to German, you need to go back to the most fundamental branch, indicating a rather large degree of separation between the two subfamilies. There may still be more similarities between the two than between either of them and e.g. Russian as the tree shown in the image above does not take the timeline of separation into account (some groups split away earlier, others later and depending on their relative split-off times they may have retained more or less differences with other branches; the Slavic languages in general being less closely related to Romance and Germanic languages than those to each other) but the long time of separation means that determining cognates requires you to derive your words back to Indo-European and then forward to the other branch.

For very closely related languages such as Danish and Swedish (same clad in the tree), a simple visual inspection is often enough to determine cognates. Comparing Swedish and Icelandic will require a slightly more thorough inspection (they still both derive from Old Norse but split earlier). Swedish and German are different still but a good number of cognates can still be identified just by ‘looking and listening’. But once you leave the Germanic sub-family, things can get complicated and dirty very quickly.

Comment: 100% correct, but there are many words that came into German as foreign words from other languages, among them Latin. But also many words that was imported from Italian or French, even from English often have Latin roots. Words like *Becken* (baccinum = shallow bowl), Kammer (camera = chamber), *kaufen* (caupo = grocer), *Kruste* (crusta = bark, shell), *Familie* (familia = family plus slaves), *Fenster* (fenestra = window), *Groschen* (grossus = gross, rough), *Mantel* (mantellum = hull, coat), *Nase* (nasus = nose), *Omen* (omen = omen) and many others are derived from Latin.

Comment: I don’t think loanwords and what became of them are considered cognates to their respective origin language words, except where the loan word was imported early enough to e.g. precede the German/Dutch split, in which case the German and Dutch ones would be cognates both deriving from the e.g. Latin word.